# how to make safari browser in full screen while running automation test

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am using java + selenium webdriver for webautomaiton. 
For safari browser 10.1 version, I need the browser to be full screen before test started.However

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

does not work

I tried few options but no luck.

1.
seems no option available for doing something like which would write in the plist file of /Library/Preferences folder of mac

defaults write com.apple.Safari

2

```
     WebElement element = Wait.wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".logo-large")));
    element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL , Keys.COMMAND , "f");
    element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL , Keys.COMMAND , "F");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("F").perform();
    action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("f").perform();
```

Is there anyway I can do it using send keys, or write in the plist file or through javascript.

Comment: You have to update the safari browser, update the browser

Comment: are you using remotedriver? or is this a local run?

Comment: This is local run in my local laptop

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
public static void maximizeScreen(WebDriver driver) {
java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Point position = new Point(0, 0);
driver.manage().window().setPosition(position);
Dimension maximizedScreenSize =
new Dimension((int) screenSize.getWidth(), (int) screenSize.getHeight());
driver.manage().window().setSize(maximizedScreenSize);
}
```

Hore it will help you

Comment: Already I am suing the above code for chrome. But it does not work for safari.  driver.manage().window().maximize(); works for firefox.

Comment: Have you tried by updating your safari driver and latest safari browser

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here (**Native Fullscreen JavaScript API**): http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

Sample:http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I tried with   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("var y = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); y.webkitRequestFullScreen();");
        js.executeScript("var y = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); y.requestFullScreen();"); but it says  org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: A JavaScript exception occured: y.webkitRequestFullScreen is not a function

Comment: Now I tried with         JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("var y = document.getElementById('root'); y.webkitRequestFullScreen();"); However its not making the fullscreen thought not giving any exception.

Comment: Take a look at source of sample code: http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/  there is a script with a comment: /* native fullscreen javascript api..*/ in that page, you need to implement something like that. Check if work by call sample url in our selenium test and simulate button click.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the safari browser, update the browser with Safari 11+ version
then you are able to maximize it using this code:

```
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: this seems not working Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\"' -e \"activate\" -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' -e 'keystroke \"f\" using {control down, command down}' -e \"end tell\" -e \"end tell\"");  but while running from command line /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application \"Safari\"' -e \"activate\" -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' -e 'keystroke \"f\" using {control down, command down}' -e \"end tell\" -e \"end tell\" its making the safari browser in full screen